# Azure - get deleted users - Using Get-AzureADUser

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm hoping to use the updated graph powershell commands to be able to pull more information on deleted users.

I'm trying to use:

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "aad.IsDeleted eq 'True'"
```

but it returns the error:

> The child type 'aaad.IsDeleted' in a cast was not an entitity type.

Ho do I filter for deleted accounts, if possible, so that I can also do a select to include additional parameters / attributes?

I'm hoping to be able to know when an account was deleted, a description, etc.

Moving some users to cloud only so we need to move them in AD to a container that is excluded from AD Connect. Then need to use a script to undelete them and validate licenses are still in use.

I know with

```
get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers
```

works, however I haven't been able to figure out how to return additional values / parameters / attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that `Get-AzureADUser` or `Get-AzADUser` have a way of filtering or returning deleted users. You can't even use `-Filter` as the property is not returned from the API call.

You can however workaround this slightly and call the API directly.

```
$result = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directory/deleteditems/microsoft.graph.user'
$jsonOutput = $result.content | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonOutput.value | Select-Object id, displayName, mail, deletedDateTime
```

There are a couple of examples on github where people have written functions to assist with making those calls:

https://github.com/Azure/GuardrailsSolutionAccelerator/blob/0f3f4994c03d8e47d7d67bd790ba3b290f37560a/src/GUARDRAIL%202%20MANAGEMENT%20OF%20ADMINISTRATIVE%20PRIVILEGES/Audit/Check-DeletedAndDisabledUsers.psm1

**and**

https://github.com/Panzerbjrn/AzureGraphApiHelper/blob/4cd2dcd1067bdabd349b044f1760bb958d54179d/AzureGraphApiHelper/Functions/Get-AGDeletedUsers.ps1

Answer (score 1):

•   You can surely get all the details of the deleted Azure AD user accounts from your tenant through the below command. Also, you can use **filter** and **attributes as shown below along with this command for sorting out specific details for a particular deleted user account**: -

**Command: -**

```
 Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers -MaxResults 50 -EnabledFilter All | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\v-kartikb\Downloads\Reatapp\delete4.csv ’
```

**Output: -**

[image: MS Online Server]

Similarly, if you want to **get any information regarding a specific user or search a user ID based on the search string**, then please refer to the below commands: -

```
 Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers | FL UserPrincipalName,ObjectID

 Get-MsolUser –ReturnDeletedUsers –SearchString <User UPN>| FLUserPrincipalName,ObjectID
```

Also, do ensure that you will have to **sign into Microsoft Office 365 service for executing the above commands successfully by executing the below command successfully**: -

```
 Connect-MsolService
```

Also, you can get the details of any deleted user if you have the object ID with you by executing the below Azure AD command through powershell: -

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject -Id <ObjectID>
```

**Output: -**

[image: Azure AD command output]

Please find the below link for more details regarding the above commands: -

***http://ajaxtechinc.com/question/manage-delete-users-office-365-recycle-bin/***

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using [the graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and the Azure CLI for auth

```
$deletedUsers = az rest `
--method "GET" `
--url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user" `
--headers "Content-Type=application/json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```